# target.status value is not defined

Tags: javascript

```
var getOptArray = function (opt) {
    var len = opt.length;
    var res = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        res.push({text: (opt[i].text), value: opt[i].value, icon: opt[i].icon, color: opt[i].color});
    }
    return res;
}

var BLOG_CATEGORY_STATUS = {
    prop: {text: "status", defval: false, class: "", size: "text-sm", margin: "m-r-xs", editable: [1, 2], tooltip: true},
    publish: {text: "publishing", value: 1, icon: "fa fa-play", color: "green", question: "Publish"},
    pause: {text: "paused", value: 2, icon: "fa fa-pause", color: "warning", question: "Pause"},
    deleted: {text: "deleted", value: 3, icon: "fa fa-trash", color: "danger", question: "Delete"},
    optArr: function () {
        return getOptArray([this.publish, this.pause, this.deleted]);
    },
    /**
     * opt example -> {status: foo, categoryId: fooValue, callback: fooFunction}
     * @param {type} opt
     */
    buildButton: function (opt) {
        opt = opt || {};
        var optArray = this.optArr();
        var targetStatus = optArray[(opt.status) - 1];
        console.log(targetStatus);
        console.log(targetStatus.color); //prints "warning"
        console.log(targetStatus.question); //prints "undefined"

        var but = {}; 
        return but;
    }
};


$(function () { 
    BLOG_CATEGORY_STATUS.buildButton({categoryId: 1 
            , status: 2
            , callback: function () {
                console.log("test");
            }})
});
```

I edit code to add as question in jsfiddle. it is ready to run in jsfiddle

in buildButton function, targetStatus.color is warning, for the same object, targetStatus.question is undefined. Can't see what i am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably missing the `question` data in the returned value from `getOptArray`:

```
res.push({
  text: opt[i].text, 
  value: opt[i].value, 
  icon: opt[i].icon, 
  color: opt[i].color, 
  question: opt[i].question    // <- here
});
```

Which, while you're at it, you should probably just rewrite this line as:

```
res.push(opt[i]);
```

Comment: How i missed it :( Thanks for response